# Preserving some characters when using to_tsvector in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql, search, text

I need to process strings like this "hello world @mention a #hashtag" and index them for searching using PostgreSQL. I do need to treat @mention and #hashtag specially.

The following produces a tsvector:

```
select to_tsvector('hello world @mention a #hashtag')
```

But the output looks like this:

```
"'a':4 'hashtag':5 'hello':1 'mention':3 'world':2"
```

What I would like is to see "@" preserved in front of 'mention' and # in front of 'hashtag'. Is there a way for me to do this using PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure tsearch is the right solution for your use case. Tsearch is good at full-text search, but it sounds like you want relational data. Can you parse the data in your application and create tag/user relationships from #hashtags and @mentions?

Comment: I lost track of this answer, but FYI -- in the end that is what we ended up doing.